# How to feed mixed data including images into deep learning model using input pipeline from tfdatasets in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

This is my first post in stackoverflow and probably very easy to answer. Due to lack of tutorials concerning this specific problem in R, though, I think this can be a great reference for R users trying to implement mixed data including images.

Specifically, my task is to fit a deep learning model with multiple inputs including image data in R for a regression task. I use tfdatasets to generate a PrefetchDataset from a text file containing the image paths and other data (preprocessing pipeline is similar to this one (https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-08-23-unet/), except for having only one image variable) that looks like this:

> training_dataset ('validation_dataset' looks similar)
>
> <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((20, 512, 512, 3), (20, 2), (20,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float64, tf.float32)>

The first tensor is the image data (batch size, width, height, channels), followed by additional numerical data (batch size, two columns) and finally the targets (batch size, one column).
I made sure that the input layers take exactly these dimensions, and compiling the model works fine.
Here's a code snippet for instantiating the model:

```
 model <- keras_model(
    inputs = c(input_cnn, input_dense),
    outputs = c(main_output)
  )
```

Basically, my question is about how to feed the dataset to the fit function. My former task was to use the image data only, and I went with this:

```
history <- model %>% fit(x = training_dataset,
                         epochs = 100,
                         steps_per_epoch = dataset_size/batch_size,
                         validation_data = validation_dataset)
```

Apparently, the y argument in fit() didn't have to be specified. With the new dataset, I get various errors, mostly the following:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
> AssertionError: in user code: ...

So far, I have tried using three separate PrefetchDatasets (Images, Additional Information, Targets) and fit it like `fit(x = list(training_dataset_images, training_dataset_additional), y = training_dataset_targets...)` but nothing like this worked. Also, I think there must be an elegant way to do this.

Software: Keras 2.3.0.0, tfdatasets 2.0.0, tensorflow 2.2.0, R 3.6.3.

Hints at the problem and how to improve my post are appreciated :-)

**EDIT**

I just want to mention that I think I found the solution, or at least a workaround that works for me. I'll share it here, because it might help others.
What I did is inserting the `dataset_prepare` function in the tfdatasets input pipeline, so that the resulting dataset looked like this:

> <PrefetchDataset shapes: {x: {img: (20, 512, 512, 3), aux: (20, 2)}, y: (20,)}, types: {x: {img: tf.float32, aux: tf.float64}, y: tf.float32}>

Then I used the following code to draw a batch from the dataset (same for validation and test datasets), which I can iterate through:

```
iter_train <- make_iterator_one_shot(training_dataset)
next_batch_train <- iterator_get_next(iter_train)
```

This way, I was able to call, e.g., the training targets of a batch using `next_batch_train$y`.

Finally, I used `train_on_batch` for training and `test_on_batch` for validation and testing, with a simple for-loop going through all the batches for each epoch until the dataset 'runs empty'. For the next epoch, I used `make_iterator_one_shot` again, and so on. I ended up coding a primitive version of parts of the Keras `fit` function myself, so that I could have a glimpse at the metrics during training and validation.

Easier solutions are appreciated :-)